# how do you run a command in a helm values.yaml to get a value?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

Right now the values.yaml has a section with

```
  username: "foo"
  password: abc123
```

I want to put the output of gcloud secrets versions access latest --secret="bar" there instead of the password.  I suppose I could do it somehow on the command line with --values or --set and $() but I am trying to use helm instead of shell.

I cannot find the docs on how to run a command in a helm values.yaml.  I think it is something like:

```
password:
  command: 
    - /bin/sh
    - -c
    - |
    - gcloud secrets versions access latest --secret="foo"
```

But just not sure.

Comment: I used the code block thing but the newlines were removed

Comment: Fixed.  The code block button puts two backticks but you actually need six.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.  There is no syntax to run an external command or do any other sort of computation in the `values.yaml` file.  In the templating language Helm uses, there is no facility to run external commands either.

The best you can do is to run this command in your host's shell and use an option like `helm install --set-string` to provide it as a Helm value.  For example,

```bash
helm install my-chart . \
  --set-string password=$(gcloud secrets versions access latest --secret="foo")
```

In the context of a CI system, you might query a secret store and write out a YAML (or JSON) file that contains the install-time values.  Then you can pass that file using a `helm install -f` option.  The `helm install --set` option has a complex syntax for nested and array-type values, if you wind up having those, but you can programmatically generate a valid JSON file from for example a `Jenkinsfile` without worrying about quoting or escaping concerns.